# Sendgrid : how to send a subject using utf8

Tags: php, html, email, utf-8, sendgrid

I send emails using Sendgrid with their PHP API.

Here is my code :

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->setSubject("blabla 25€");
..
$content = new Content("text/plain", $body_plain);
$mail->addContent($content);
$content = new Content("text/html", $body_html);
$mail->addContent($content);

// We send the transactional email
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
```

**Result :**

Instead of "blabla 25€", I reveive emails with this subject :

> blabla 25â‚¬

**I tried :**

```
$subject = utf8_encode("blabla 25€");
```

**Result :**

the same..

Is it possible to use UTF8 subject with Sendgrid ? Is it a bug?

Any idea why it doesn't work?